# table.addItem is not adding the value to my table

Tags: vaadin

When I add the table.addContainerProperty manually (all of them) it works, adding all items i ask for.

When I use a for to create the table.addContainerProperty I cannot add values using my button, or with the for that should add all my values.

Why? I cannot find it anywhere...

```
package br.com.Metrics;

import com.vaadin.Application; import
com.vaadin.ui.Button; import
com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table; import
com.vaadin.ui.Window;

import br.com.cflex.table.*;

/**  * The Application's "main" class 
*/ @SuppressWarnings("serial") public class MyVaadinApplication extends Application {
    private Window window;
    private Table table;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        window = new Window("My Vaadin Application");

        table = new Table("Teste de tabela");
        table.addItem();
        table.addContainerProperty("Nome", String.class, null);

        for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
            table.addContainerProperty(i,Integer.class, null);
            table.addItem(new Object[] {"2",new Integer(159),new Integer(1473)}, null);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            table.addItem(new Object[] {"3",new Integer(159),new Integer(1473)}, null);
        }

        table.addItem(new Object[] {"4",new Integer(159),new Integer(1473)}, null);

        Button button = new Button("Press Me !");
        button.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {     
             table.addItem(new Object[] {"Nicolaus",new Integer(159),new Integer(1473)}, null);
            }
        });
        window.addComponent(table);
        window.addComponent(button);        
        setMainWindow(window);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why...

when inserting data in a table using .addItem the array that you must provide to this method **MUST** have the exact same number of itens as the table columns.

otherwise it will not add them or tell you that.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The API tells you that addItem() will return the ID of the added Item, or null if the operation fails. You're not checking the addItem() return values, so you don't know if the calls fail or not.

Comment: @hezamu Still it tells you that adding the item failed, but not why

Comment: @golimar That's true, though it's usually a good idea to use BeanItemContainer instead of "hardwiring" the container properties with the table directly.